# View Expansion in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, view

So we have some developers who went a little view happy. So now we have views that reference views that reference views, ad nauseum.

So what I want, in order to assist me in Tuning, is to expand these views.

I want a function that takes a string and returns a string. The input string is the query, the output string is the same query without views.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW myView AS
SELECT * FROM emp
```

Using function/stored procedure "F":

```
F('SELECT * FROM myView')
```

...would return:

```
SELECT * FROM ( SELECT * FROM emp)
```

---

1. Is there an Oracle package for this?
2. Does someone have code in:

   1. either SQL or PL/SQL
   2. In something else

Comment: Is there a view naming convention to go along with the madness?

Comment: `SELECT dv.TEXT_LENGTH FROM DBA_VIEWS dv WHERE dv.view_name = 'myview'` will return the view definition.  The fun part is knowing what is a view and what isn't in the query, in the various spots it can occur.

Comment: Naming convention, yes, but strictly followed no.

Comment: Yes I know that I could build this. But I would do it very poorly. I bet this could be done in Regex, maybe? or SQL. It's almost a code-golf but it's not the point to just do it for golfing, I actually need this.

Comment: @OMG Ponies: One could use the `*DEPENDENCIES` views to determine if a view is dependent upon another view (and also to get the dependent sub-view names). Of course if the name of the view is also present in the text of the query as an alias or in a comment  this could lead to additional fun...

Comment: @vincent... yeh, like that. that's what I'm saying. But it's not as hard as you say. The name of the view could appear in many place in the query but the only one that would count is after a FROM and BEFORE WHERE or GROUP BY or ORDER BY or HAVING whichever comes first. Then it would be the first word before a space or after a comma.

Comment: Looks like Oracle have listened to you :) see my updated answer

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Short answer:

1. Not at this time
2. Not that I'm aware of

**UPDATE**

It looks like Oracle 12c has exactly what you need: `DBMS_UTILITY.expand_sql_text`

http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E16655_01/appdev.121/e17602/d_util.htm#ARPLS73973

Answer (score 3):

One problem with what you are proposing is that there are usually multiple ways that a query involving views can be rewritten, so simply expanding the text of the views won't necessarily tell you a lot about how the query is being executed.

Since your purpose is tuning, I would suggest that the execution plans for the queries will probably give you the information you really need.  This won't show the rewritten query, but it will show you all the actual tables and how they are referenced in executing the query.

The best way I know of to view the actual execution plan is:

```
SELECT /*+ gather_plan_statistics */ * FROM myView

select * from table(dbms_xplan.display_cursor(null,null,'ALLSTATS LAST'))
```

Comment: You're not understanding. I don't care about retrieving the execution plan... I want the actual SQL... and there's only one way a view is written. It's not multiple choice... CREATE VIEW myView AS SELECT * FROM table. If I passed in myView I want "SELECT * FROM table" as the return value.

Comment: I understand that I did not answer your question directly.  Since someone had already pointed out that the answer to your specific question is simply "no", I was trying to suggest an alternative that might be helpful.  My point about rewriting is that if your interest is in tuning queries, my experience is that simply expanding the view text is of limited utility, and that understanding the actual execution of the query is much more useful.

Answer (score 1):

There are some methods to expand views but the output is so ugly it may not be useful.

**12c** Has a new procedure named [DBMS_UTILITY.EXPAND_SQL_TEXT](http://docs.oracle.com/database/121/ARPLS/d_util.htm#ARPLS73973).

**11g** Has an undocumented procedure [dbms_sql2.expand_sql_text](https://jonathanlewis.wordpress.com/2012/07/10/expanding-sql/).

Below is a simple example.  The output may be helpful for the optimizer but it is probably not much use if you need a human-readable SQL statement.

```
create or replace view view1 as select 1 a, 2 b from dual;
create or replace view view2 as select a from view1;

declare
    v_output clob;
begin
    dbms_utility.expand_sql_text('select * from view2', v_output);
    dbms_output.put_line(v_output);
end;
/

Output:
SELECT "A1"."A" "A" FROM  (SELECT "A2"."A" "A" FROM  (SELECT 1 "A",2 "B" FROM "SYS"."DUAL" "A3") "A2") "A1"
```